# WebParts drag and drop not working in IE 11

Tags: web-parts

I just cant get my webparts change their zone in design mode. Tried everything but doesn't help

```
<asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
            <StaticConnections>
                <asp:WebPartConnection ID="connection1"
                    ConsumerConnectionPointID="ZipCodeConsumer"
                    ConsumerID="zipConsumer"
                    ProviderConnectionPointID="ZipCodeProvider"
                    ProviderID="zipProvider" />
            </StaticConnections>
        </asp:WebPartManager>
        <div class="div1">
            <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server" AllowLayoutChange="true">
                <ZoneTemplate>
                    <uc1:UserCtrlForProperty runat="server" ID="UserCtrlForProperty"/>
                    <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" Title="Select Movie/Book">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Books" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Movies" Value="M"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:BulletedList>

                </ZoneTemplate>
            </asp:WebPartZone>
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone2" runat="server" AllowLayoutChange="true">
                <ZoneTemplate>
                    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Title="My Static Calendar"></asp:Calendar>
                </ZoneTemplate>
            </asp:WebPartZone>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WebParts don't work in all versions of IE.

Comment: ehhh... no. 

That is simply not true. WebParts works. They may have issues at times, but "don't work" ;-)